# How to describe a "sum percentile"

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology, random-variables

I have values $w_1 \ge w_2 \ge ..\ge w_n$. I want to know the the highest possible threshold $w^{th}$ so that

$$ \sum_{i:w_i>w^{th}} w_i \ge \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n w_i $$

where $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Basically I'm looking for an $\alpha$-percentile of the sum of values - can I call it that?

I know how to get to the $w^{th}$ for a specific sample: I calculate the sum of all values. Then I iteratively add decreasing values until I reach $\alpha$ percent of the total sum.

What I want to know: Is there a name of this "sum percentile"? How to calculate it for a known distribution of values? Should I create a new random variable $S=\sum w_i $ and find the percentiles of the distribution of $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term weight ususally connotes  a value such that $\sum w_{i} = 1$. Is that the case here, or are the weights simply sample values? From your subsequent text, it seems the latter is true. Given that, it is not clear the solution exists for all $\alpha$ for a specific sample, as you have a discrete set of weights but a continuous $\alpha$. Also, if you are trying to get the threshold for the general case, then it will be a random variable, not a fixed number, and will depend not only on the distribution of the "weights" as you call them, but also the sample size.

In plain language, it looks like you are trying to find the order statistic of a sample of N values such that the sum of all the higher order statistics is $\alpha$ percent of the sum of all the order statistics. Since the N order statistics are random, you could call this the order-fraction distribution, $O(\alpha,(i))$ with (i) being the order statistic in question. The distribution will be discrete on {1,2,...N} and will give the probability that the $i^{th}$ order statistic is the $\alpha$ threshold.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To clear some things up: yes, the weights are simply sample values. Also, I was a bit unprecise: I want the cutoff so that *at least* $\alpha$ percent are contained in the sum of retained values, I will edit my question accordingly. I am now looking into the rest of your answer to see if this answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think my suggestion still holds with the slight change that you are calculating the probability that the (ith) order statistic = $\sup\{i:\sum_{i:w_i>w^{th}} w_i \ge \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\}$

Comment: I think what you describe in your second paragraph is the proper terminology of what I'm trying to say in my second paragraph. This is certainly helpful ("order statistic" is a term that didn't come to my mind). I was hoping this "order-fraction distribution" might be a thing, but this doesn't seem to be the case - no google hits.

Comment: Sorry...I see you were looking for a common name for this. I offered a name, but as you found, it is one I put together to hopefully capture the essence of what you are trying to do...find the order statistic that is a given fraction of a sum. I guess you can also say order-exceedance fraction to be more precise. Either way, I think youll have to explain your sum in any paper as I have never seen it in my work as a standard calculation.

Comment: Another idea: I just noticed a pretty good analogy between your sum percentile and the Pareto Principle (80/20 rule): You are trying to find the fewest number of individuals who can account for a given fraction of a total. You may want to call it a Pareto-Ranked Sum, since you are simply starting witht the larges value and adding until S(N>n)<$\alpha$ and S(N>n-1)>$\alpha$. Anyway, just another avenue to look into. There is also the pareto distribution that may bear some relation to this, so you may want to peruse the article on it:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParetoDistribution.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've given me some really nice ways to look at my problem, and most of all clarified that there isn't a standard way of looking at it (which is still somewhat surprising to me!).